# How to deal with lack of place to brush my teeth at work

Tags: health

When you are at work 8h it's not good not to brush your teeth (unless you don't eat anything during that time).

At my work place we have 2 places with sinks:

- kitchen (by the way, is there any proper name for it in English? a place with fridge, sink, table and microwave but at workplace)
- toilettes

Neither of those places fits to one brush its teeth, because

- kitchen's sink is filled with dirty dishes most of the time
- toilette area seems so slipery and slimmy that I would rather keep my toothbrush away

**So wow to deal with lack of place to brush my teeth at work?**

Comment: I don't see the problem. You bring your toothbrush and the toothpaste, start the tap, water the toothbrush, stop the tap, put the paste onto the brush, then brush the teeth, start the tap, wash the brush, rinse your mouth, stop the tap. How do the dishes and slippery toilet make any problems? Btw it sounds like *how do I brush my teeth at world's end* which might be a good fit for Travel SE.

Comment: Have you considered a toothbrush cover/protector so that you can hygienically store it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand something, do you wish to keep your toothbrush in the restroom?

Answer (score 5):

It might actually be worthwhile to address the dirty dishes in the kitchen sink, which I would argue are a problem all by themselves - at the very least, they are unhygienic.

Alternatively, you could also address the cleanliness in your restrooms. Do you have a cleaning service? If so, and if you can't bring yourself to brush your teeth in the restroom *after it has supposedly been cleaned*, I would say that the cleaning service is not doing its job.

If neither of these approaches work, you could maybe go outside with a bottle of water and rinse your mouth (discreetly) near some bushes. Or you could chew sugar-free gum.

Comment: If you decide to go with the sugar-free gum, be careful on how much you use. It usually acts as a weaker laxative.

Comment: Yeah, and I think it's overrated because it actually won't help your teeth

Answer (score 1):

Colgate makes a waterless/rinsless brush system called the [wisp.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001TH8Y60)
They're kind of pricey and more of an emergency type of thing, but it may help the situation.

To expand a bit on @Stephan Kolassa's bit about gum. They do make a dentist recommended type that contains xylitol. It helps with enamel restoration too.  I would do some research on those types of gums before choosing one and make sure you follow the directions. I'm not a dentist or a doctor as a caveat, but my dentist told me to use xylitol gum.

Comment: Be careful with xylitol gum if you have pets. It will kill a dog.